# Deal with large data set in WPF Application Using SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, wpf, sql-server-ce

I recently developed a prototype WPF prototype application that accesses a SQL Server CE database via Entity Framework. Now there is a need to access a data set well above the 4GB limit of SQL CE, approximately 29GB.

I would like to know what the best option would be to scale to this new requirement. The options I can think of are:

1. Move to SQL Server. This would require purchasing licenses and I don't believe deploying the application would be as smooth?
2. Use multiple SQL CE databases. There are in fact 36 objects that I am trying to store each with an approximate size of 800MB once loaded into SQL CE (800MB * 36 = 29GB). I wonder if there would be any performance issues simultaneously connecting to 36 SQL CE databases.

How would you tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Move to SQL Server. You are in a world of pain trying to work with a 29gb dataset with manual sharding, including you miss all the backup / restopre goodies.

Comment: Not really concerned about the backup/restore goodies as it will be a static data set and the original data that it is derived from will always be preserved. What is your opinion on having a separate SQL CE .sdf file for each of the 36 objects?

Comment: Simple: I use a database as it is designed, and CE is not designed for large data sets. I would not do it.